# regex for ordering/numbering

Tags: python, regex

I need to create a regex to capture the ordering (a),(b),(c) within a text, and add a line break before it, such as:

> The Integrated Programme Framework of the ISSSS  has been established to: (a) create a protective     environment for civilians by strengthening the security forces, and improving discipline and control; (b) support the demobilization and reintegration of armed groups; (c) re-establish state functions in areas formerly controlled by armed groups, through the training and deployment of state officials (police, penitentiary, judicial and administration) to uphold the rule of law and public order, (d) ensure open road access and infrastructure; (e) promote a safe and dignified return of internally displaced persons and refugees; and (f) address priority social needs and key sources of conflict and initiate economic recovery.

and I'd like to extend it to numbers (1),(2),(3)... and Roman Numerals (I),(II),(III).../ (i),(ii),(iii)

A further challenge, can we make it match any Style, such as A- B- C- or A. B. C. or A) B) C) ?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print re.sub("\((I+|i+|[a-z0-9])\)","\n\g<0>",buff)
```

will generate

```
The Integrated Programme Framework of the ISSSS has been established to: 
(a) create a protective environment for civilians by strengthening the security forces,     and improving discipline and control; 
(b) support the demobilization and reintegration of armed groups; 
(c) re-establish state functions in areas formerly controlled by armed groups, through     the training and deployment of state officials (police, penitentiary, judicial     and administration) to uphold the rule of law and public order, 
(d) ensure open road access and infrastructure; 
(e) promote a safe and dignified return of internally displaced persons and refugees; and 
(f) address priority social needs and key sources of conflict and initiate economic recovery.
```

I'd be leery of making a totally 'universal' one just because you run into hyphenated word issues, such as 're-establish'.  The above regex should cover a majority of your cases, and you should be able to tailor it easily by adding or removing stuff inside the '|' operator. That being said, I played a little more with it, added a test sentence, and it works well enough. I had to make the assumption that I started with a space to avoid some of the potential problems like ')', '.", or '-' being used.

```
>>> buff += "This is a) test of i) one ii) two iii) three a. four and b- five"
>>> print re.sub(" \({0,1}(I+|i+|[a-zA-Z0-9])(\)|\.|-)","\n\g<0>",buff)

The Integrated Programme Framework of the ISSSS has been established to:
 (a) create a protective environment for civilians by strengthening the security forces, and improving discipline and control;
 (b) support the demobilization and reintegration of armed groups;
 (c) re-establish state functions in areas formerly controlled by armed groups, through the training and deployment of state officials (police, penitentiary, judicial and administration) to uphold the rule of law and public order,
 (d) ensure open road access and infrastructure;
 (e) promote a safe and dignified return of internally displaced persons and refugees; and
 (f) address priority social needs and key sources of conflict and initiate economic recovery.This is
 a) test of
 i) one
 ii) two
 iii) three
 a. four and
 b- five
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sub with a callback;

```
import re

subject = 'The Integrated Programme Framework of the ISSSS has been established to: (a) create a protective environment for civilians by strengthening the security forces, and improving discipline and control; (b) support the demobilization and reintegration of armed groups; (c) re-establish state functions in areas formerly controlled by armed groups, through the training and deployment of state officials (police, penitentiary, judicial and administration) to uphold the rule of law and public order, (d) ensure open road access and infrastructure; (e) promote a safe and dignified return of internally displaced persons and refugees; and (f) address priority social needs and key sources of conflict and initiate economic recovery.'

def callback_f(e):
    # Check your input
    if e.group()[1] == 'a':
        print(e.group()[1])
        return '(1)'
    else:
        print(e.group()[1])
        return '(' + e.group()[1] + ')';

result = re.sub(r'\((\w)\)', callback_f, subject)

print(result)
```

I'm not going into this with great extend. But you could use a dictionary to automatically replace your `a/b/c/d/e` values with whatever it will match in your mapping.

This demo outputs in the Terminal;

```
192:Desktop allendar$ python test.py 
a
b
c
d
e
f
The Integrated Programme Framework of the ISSSS has been established to: A create a protective environment for civilians by strengthening the security forces, and improving discipline and control; (b) support the demobilization and reintegration of armed groups; (c) re-establish state functions in areas formerly controlled by armed groups, through the training and deployment of state officials (police, penitentiary, judicial and administration) to uphold the rule of law and public order, (d) ensure open road access and infrastructure; (e) promote a safe and dignified return of internally displaced persons and refugees; and (f) address priority social needs and key sources of conflict and initiate economic recovery.
```